# Google Maps SDK for iOS and libc++

Tags: ios, libstdc++, libc++, google-maps-sdk-ios

In our project we use library that use libc++ in its implementation very tightly. And when we added Google Maps SDK we got linkage error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
     gmscore::utils::gmsutils::StringPrintf(char const*, ...) in GoogleMaps(GMSUtils.o)
     _GMS_objc_lookUpClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getProtocol in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     gmscore::vector::CameraPosition::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(CameraPosition.o)

 "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
     gmscore::utils::gmsutils::StringPrintf(char const*, ...) in GoogleMaps(GMSUtils.o)
     _GMS_objc_lookUpClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getProtocol in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     gmscore::vector::CameraPosition::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(CameraPosition.o)
     gmscore::utils::gmsutils::StringPrintf(char const*, ...) in GoogleMaps(GMSUtils.o)
     _GMS_objc_lookUpClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getProtocol in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     gmscore::vector::CameraPosition::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(CameraPosition.o)
     gmscore::utils::gmsutils::StringPrintf(char const*, ...) in GoogleMaps(GMSUtils.o)
     _GMS_objc_lookUpClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getClass in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     _GMS_objc_getProtocol in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
     gmscore::vector::CameraPosition::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(CameraPosition.o)

 "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
     gmscore::utils::gmsutils::StringPrintf(char const*, ...) in GoogleMaps(GMSUtils.o)
     gmscore::model::Point2D::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(Point2D.o)

 "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
     gmscore::utils::gmsutils::StringPrintf(char const*, ...) in GoogleMaps(GMSUtils.o)
     gmscore::vector::CameraPosition::StringValue() const in GoogleMaps(CameraPosition.o)
```

It's happened because google maps sdk use libstdc++ library, but we can not change code which use libc++. We tried to encapsulate code and library which use libc++ in static library (*.a), but without success. 
Any chance to make things work? Maybe, it's possible to link Google Maps SDK with libc++?

Comment: You might need to raise a feature request for this one: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5036 thumb up

Comment: Feature request was implemented in last Google Maps SDK for iOS release. So it is not problem already. Thanks for your support. Please, close question.

Answer (score 5):

The undefined symbols you are seeing are symbols associated with libstdc++.  libstdc++ and libc++ are largely ABI incompatible, even though they present to you (largely) the same API.

In places where the ABI incompatibility is known, such as `std::string`, libc++ uses a different mangling scheme so that libstdc++ and libc++ strings are not accidentally mixed at run time (which would cause hard-to-debug run time errors).

If you see symbols that have `std::__1` in their name, then those are symbols associated libc++, e.g. libc++ has `std::__1::basic_string<...`, where as libstdc++ has `std::basic_string<...`.

You can use this knowledge of mangling to help you determine which libraries are needing which implementations of the std::lib.

Filing the feature request you did was the very best thing you could do, and thank you for doing that! :-)

Comment: It's very interesting knowledge, but we really need both libc++ for another, important for us, libriry and libstdc++ for Google Maps SDK. Code which link with these libraries, do not intersect, we even use them in different controller. If exist linkage flag for compiling source likewise "-no-objc-arc"...